# Conflict between EJS and Marionette

Tags: marionette, ejs

For my single page application, the page is delivered by node-express-ejs on the server side to Maironette-Backbone based client on the browser. Unfortunately, both EJS and Marionette use the syntax "<%= var %>" for plugging in computed values. My page has some values that need to be plugged in by the server and some that will be computed by the client. So I need something like the following snippet to work.

```
    <html> .....

    Server Computed = $ <%=serverComputed%>

    Client Computed = $ <%=clientComputed%>

    ....</html>
```

And my routes.js on the server would have something like,

```
    res.render('test', { serverComputed: '5000' });
```

But, EJS throws

```
    ReferenceError:  .../test.ejs:17

    .....

    clientComputed is not defined
```

The following does not help either

```
    res.render('test', { serverComputed: '5000', clientComputed: '<%= clientComputed %>' });
```

since it as expected, ends up as

```
    $lt:%= clientComputed %&gt;
```

Is there a way (a market, a processor directive etc) to tell EJS processor to not process a part of the file?

Is there any other way to work around this conflict?

Thanks,

Hemant

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

EJS does allow defining your own tags by setting them in the options. So far as I can tell, this is not documented. I only found it by going through the source code. Anyway, the following option setting would avoid conflict with Marionette open-close tags.

On server side, routes.js can specify options like this.

```
    res.render('test', { open: '{{', close: '}}', serverComputed: '5000'  });
```

In the ejs file, now you can have different markups for server-computed and client-computed variables, like so.

```
    Server Computed = $ {{=serverComputed}}

    Client Computed = $ <%=clientComputed%>
```

EJS processor will not process the "<%=clientComputed%>" part.

Hemant